# Erro na SQL QUERY

Tags: sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table 
GROUP BY (YEAR_MONTH FROM data)
ORDER BY (YEAR_MONTH FROM data) ASC
```

Está a dar erro no _YEAR_MONTH_ e não sei porque

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse SQL foi feito em qual banco? Coloque a mensagem de erro para facilitar a identificação do problema.

Comment: Não está faltando a função EXTRACT? `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM data)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pela sintaxe acredito que esteja usando `mysql`. Sendo assim, acredito que tenha esquecido o [`extract`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month).

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM table 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM data)
ORDER BY EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM data) ASC
```

Comment: Vi agora que [@EmanuelF](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/37939/emanuelf) comentou o mesmo que respondi aqui, então tenta isso mesmo.